# Why use Service Bus when deploying EPiServer CMS to Azure?

Tags: azureservicebus, episerver, azure-web-app-service, episerver-7

My task is to deploy an EpiServer 7 CMS site that has been running on-prem VM to Azure web app, two instances.

In the guide I found at link is telling me to set up Service Bus. Does anyone know why I need the SB? http://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/Deployment/deployment-scenarios/Deploying-to-Azure-webapps/

**Additional comments:**

I have a problem in following scenario: I´m logging in to EPi on instance1 on my browser, and then I turn an image upside down. This does not affect instance 2 that I have open in another browser, even after reloading the page. Is this something that the Service Bus is there to handle?

I will create another question thread for this, but: Is there any other way except blob storage to store my images so that updates on instance1 will affect instance2?

Answer (score 3):

Your additional comments are related to the Service Bus. Service Bus will handle event messages between all instances, these messages may contain cache invalidation information. The event system is pluggable, so you can create your own implementation if you don't want to rely on Service Bus. But you need to enable events so instances knows when to invalidate the cache.

Answer (score 1):

The service bus is needed to ensure the Episerver web app can run in **multiple instances** (i.e. *servers*) in Azure, for example to trigger cache invalidation of other instance(s) when content changes in one instance.